# Self made remove if is space

Tags: c++, mingw

I am learning C++ and for practice, am making a four function calculator. I am trying (for practice reasons) to make my own function that removes all spaces from a string. The function compiles but the program crashes when the function is executed. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Function:

```
int operate(std::string inRaw) {
    // Parsing
    int j = 0;
    int inMinLen;
    int inLen = inRaw.length();
    std::string inSub, in[inLen];
    for(int i = 0; i < inLen; i++) {
        inSub = inRaw.substr(i, 1);
        while(inSub != " ") {
            in[j] = inSub;
            j++;
        }
        inMinLen = j+1;
    }
    std::string inMin[inMinLen];
    for(int k = 0; k < inMinLen; k++) {
        inMin[k] = in[k];
        std::cout << in[k]; // DEBUG
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you *doing* there? Regarding efficiency (or simpilicity, too), this is just scary. Two arrays, with whole string objects for *each* source char, as many substr calls etc.etc. ...

Comment: If you are comfortable with calling functions like substr, just use std::replace . It´s one line. If you really want your own function, loop over chars and nothing more.

Comment: @deviantfan As I said, I am still learning C++ and most likely do not know the most efficient way.

Comment: [One-line C++ solutiion](http://ideone.com/MJn0zE)

Comment: @KerrekSB I didn't want to use  `<string>.erase()`.

Comment: @Krii So substr is ok, but no other functions which are more suited...?

Comment: @deviantfan I wouldn't know how to get the sub string on my own. I guess I will look in the header files.

Comment: @Krii Instead of `std::string inSub = inRaw.substr(i, 1);` you could jst use `char inSub = inRaw[i];` (and change the code accordingly because a single char is not a whole string)

Comment: @deviantfan Then I'm guessing a string is just an array of chars. I will try.

Comment: @Krii Essentially, it is (and like written above, it even offers `[]` to access single elements, altough in reality std::string is a class with the array inside of it. The real benefit of std::string are the methods it offers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This while loop:

```
    while(inSub != " ") {
```

will never finish as you never change the value of `insub` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, a function without calling any predefined string
functions/methods except for size, and with only one array:

```
void operate(std::string inRaw) {
    size_t len = inRaw.length();
    size_t current = 0;
    char *data = new char[len + 1];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        data[current] = inRaw[i];
        if(data[current] != ' ')
            current++;
    }

    data[current] = '\0';
    cout << data << endl;
    delete[] data;
}
```

But a solution like in KerrekSB´s example is preferable anyways.